# Does OPOS Bridge for UWP PointOfService support OPOS Barcode Scanners

Tags: c#, uwp, barcode-scanner, opos, pointofservice

I am attempting to use an [HP 4430 2d Imaging Barcode Scanner (BW868AA)](https://support.hp.com/us-en/product/hp-imaging-barcode-scanner/5061524/model/5061525?sku=BW868AA) with the UWP app using the **PointOfService API**.

The barcode scanner is not in the list of [officially supported hardware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/pos-device-support) for  the UWP PointOfService library.  The scanner also does not have support for USB-HID-POS mode or USB-HID-POS drivers.

My question is this: **Does the *OPOS Bridge* that was released in the Creator's Update support barcode scanners in OPOS mode?**

This [video](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2017/P4050) from [Terry Warwick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9523542/terry-warwick) introduces the OPOS Bridge, which adds OPOS support for usb printers, cash drawers, and line displays.  But I cannot tell if barcode scanners in OPOS mode are supposed to be detected with this OPOS bridge as well.

Currently, we have the barcode scanner working with OPOS using various OPOS testing utilities.  But it is not detected in the UWP Barcode sample app.

Comment: It looks like nothing, so you will need to create your own OPOS Brigde for barcode scanners using the Scale sample code introduced in the video. [Desktop Bridge OPOS scale Sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/DesktopBridgeToUWP-Samples/tree/master/Samples/DesktopBridgeOPOSscale)

Comment: Thanks @kunif, but I’m not sure what you mean when you say “it looks like nothing”. Can you elaborate?  I know Desktop Bridge is an option, but just want a definitive answer that the already provided OPOS bridge is not intended to support barcode scanners

Comment: I’ve looked for the OPOS bridge implementation to answer definitely for myself, but cannot seem to find where that code is. I assume it’s open source

Comment: The reason is that there is no description of OPOS in the scanner connectivity on the "officially supported hardware" page that you indicated. Cash Drawer, LineDisplay, POSPrinter describes OPOS. It is a technique that has been introduced and is probably not used, but there is a library called [BrokeredPointOfService](https://github.com/apulliam/BrokeredPointOfService). As an open source, this would also be a candidate.

Comment: As an alternative, you could consider using the scanner in keyboard input mode, giving up using OPOS or PointOfService.

Answer (score 1):

No, Barcode Scanners are not part of the OPOS bridge for UWP.  It is recommend to set a scanner in keyboard mode or in HID POS Scanner mode (if supported).
[Configure a barcode scanner](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/pos-barcodescanner-configure)

The OPOS drivers through UWP Bridge work for USB POS Printers, Cash Drawers, and Line Displays. See [Supported Point of Service Peripherals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/pos-device-support) , Microsoft will indicate if the device is supported through OPOS.

As the commentor suggested, that scanner would likely need to be used as a Keyboard Wedge given that it does not support HID POS Scanner mode nor is it on the list of supported devices for UWP.

Comment: Thanks Aaron, all correct.  Keep in mind that using a scanner in keyboard mode simply makes the scanner look like a keyboard to the system as opposed to being able to control the scanner from your application.  Alternatively you can use https://aka.ms/desktopbridge to add a Win32 process to your UWP application then talk to the scanner using POS for .NET or even OPOS in your UWP application.  See Build 2017 presentation which describes this option: https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2017/P4050